# Hubot Unit Testing Not Receiving Response

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, chai, hubot

I'm trying to set up a simple unit test for my hubot code and I am not receiving responses back.  I have simplified this down to:

test.coffee:

```
Helper = require('hubot-test-helper')
chai = require 'chai'
expect = chai.expect
helper = new Helper('../hubot-scripts/something.coffee')

describe 'PING', ->
    beforeEach ->
        @room = helper.createRoom()
    afterEach ->
        @room.destroy

    it 'should PONG', ->
        @room.user.say 'alice', '@hubot PING'
        expect(@room.messages).to.eql [
            ['alice', '@hubot PING'],
            ['hubot', 'PONG']
        ]
```

and something.coffee:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.response /PING$/i, (msg) ->
        msg.send 'PONG'
```

When I run my tests, I get an assertion error of:

```
  AssertionError: expected [ [ 'alice', '@hubot PING' ] ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
  + expected - actual

     [
       "alice"
       "@hubot PING"
     ]
  +  [
  +    "hubot"
  +    "PONG"
  +  ]
   ]
```

Meaning I am not getting a response back at all.  I have tried changing @hubot to hubot (which shouldn't matter).  I also verified that it is finding my something.coffee, as when I changed that path to an incorrect one I received an error about that.

I am following the example at bottom of https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who reached this thread, I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019357/assertionerror-while-testing-hubot-script-with-hubot-test-helper-and-chai/56021721#56021721) when I experienced the same issue.
In short, the issue was indentation - the line beginning with `expect` was being called before the `@room.user.say` was executed. Please see my link for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but moving the @room.user.say into a before block made this work.

Comment: Can you post your code, please? I'm having the same issue, but can't understand your instructions. I've created a before -> and place my entire test in there.