# AssertionError while testing Hubot script with hubot-test-helper and chai

Tags: debugging, testing, coffeescript, hubot

I'm writing a simple test for my Hubot (which acts as a Slack bot) to check that my bot sends a reply in response to triggers. I've followed the example shown in the [docs](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/#testing-hubot-scripts), but test results in an `AssertionError` (details below) and I'm not sure why. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I assume the issue has to do with the test, not the script (`break-start.coffee`), since I got the correct reply when I tested the script by sending an actual message to the bot from Slack.

```coffee
# break-start.coffee
# Basically, the bot says "Later alligator" to any user going on lunch break.

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /off to lunch/i, (res) ->
    res.reply('Later alligator')
```

```coffee
# break-start-test.coffee

'use strict'

Helper = require('hubot-test-helper')
helper = new Helper('../scripts/break-start.coffee')
request = require('request')
expect = require('chai').expect

describe 'bot responds to user message', ->
  beforeEach ->
    # Set up the room before running the test.
    @room = helper.createRoom()

  afterEach ->
    # Tear it down after the test to free up the listener.
    @room.destroy()

  it 'responds to users who are off to lunch', ->
    @room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch').then =>
    expect(@room.messages).to.eql [
        ['bob', '@hubot Off to lunch']
        ['hubot', '@bob Later alligator']
      ]
```

```
# The error message

AssertionError: expected [ [ 'bob', '@hubot Off to lunch' ] ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
      + expected - actual

         [
           "bob"
           "@hubot Off to lunch"
         ]
      +  [
      +    "hubot"
      +    "@bob Later alligator"
      +  ]
       ]
```

By the way, there was an extremely similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447909/hubot-unit-testing-not-receiving-response) posted here before but it went unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is an indentation error.

The `@room.user.say` call is being passed an empty function as a promise resolution rather than the expect block, as this should be indented another level.

That fits with the result that only one message is in the room, as the `expect` call got executed before the async `@room.user.say()` got executed:

```
it 'responds to users who are off to lunch', ->
  @room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch').then =>
    expect(@room.messages).to.eql [
      ['bob', '@hubot Off to lunch']
      ['hubot', '@bob Later alligator']
    ]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.